# Django Pass Request Data to Forms.py

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

The scenario;

We got a from with fields and inside form there is a combobox, it fills with items.

We have tenancy and every user got TenantID so when A1 user(tenantid 1) calls create form, we need to filter that combobox to filter only A1 UserItems with using Query Filtering.

Similarly for other tenants.

How can I pass that dynamic tenantid.

Btw for every user tenantid stored in abstracted class django core USER- added new field tenantid.
Any advice Im open for it, thank you for your attention.

**State: Solved !**

**Forms.py**

```
class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Items
        fields = ('id', 'item', 'start', 'end')
        widgets = {
            'start': DateTimePickerInput(format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'),
            'end': DateTimePickerInput(format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['item'].queryset = Items.objects.filter(tenantid=int(User.tenantid))
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required()
def create_item_record(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ItemForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        tenantidX = request.user.tenantid
        form = ItemForm()
    return save_item_form(request, form, 'items_create_partial.html')
```

Comment: for such kind of filtering, you probably need to render them dynamically using ajax, rather than raw django form.

Comment: there should be a way at least pass parameter while calling form on view side maybe.

Comment: You can also segregate your form into various pages, so that you can keep filtering at each step.

Comment: What about your code doesn't work?  Also, why doesn't GwynBleidD's code not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the best and easy way of getting current request with using  "django -crum" https://pypi.org/project/django-crum/ .

```
pip install django-crum
```

after that add to settings.py

```
# settings.py
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
 'crum.CurrentRequestUserMiddleware',
...
)
```

include lib

```
from crum import get_current_request

request = get_current_request()
```

Then you can reach active request inside with **request.user.tenantid**

Comment: Thanks alot dude

Answer (score 6):

Just pass user from request to your form:

```
class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Items
        fields = ('id', 'item', 'start', 'end')
        widgets = {
            'start': DateTimePickerInput(format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'),
            'end': DateTimePickerInput(format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'),
        }

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['item'].queryset = Items.objects.filter(tenantid=int(user.tenantid))

@login_required()
def create_item_record(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ItemForm(request.user, request.POST)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ItemForm(request.user)
    return save_item_form(request, form, 'items_create_partial.html')
```

Comment: how can I accept incoming parameter to form , as I did it wont work

Comment: Look at the form in my answer, there is `user` parameter added to it. You should use that.

Comment: yes I did what u added but gives error object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: I do believe @GwynBleidD solution is correct. I suggest you to give it one more chance ;)

Comment: @BCA Please provide a traceback for that error.  It is impossible to help you otherwise, since no `.get` call is made here.